# Draw androidx AndroidPath on Canvas

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-view, android-graphics

i want to draw androidx androidPath on canvas by using AndroidPath class which is extending Path Class.It is defined in
androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Path

reference :
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/graphics/AndroidPath#quadraticBezierTo(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float)

but canvas.drawPath take only path not androidPath

```
public void drawPath(@NonNull Path path, @NonNull Paint paint) {
    super.drawPath(path, paint);
}
```

can anyone suggest me any way to draw androidx AndroidPath on canvas ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If AndroidPath extends Path, then it can be used wherever a Path object is expected.  Because it is a Path object.  It's just also an AndroidPath object.  That's how inheritance works.